# Computing the joint distribution of two variables $X$ and $Y$

Tags: probability

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two random variables with joint and uniform distribution over the region $x \leqslant 1$, $y \leqslant 1$ and $x+y \leqslant 1$. Compute the joint probability density of $X$ and $Y$ and the marginal probability density of each variable. Check for independency. Compute $Pr\left(X \leqslant a | Y \leqslant B\right)$.

I know how to find the marginals (integrating the joint function in $X$ for $Y$ and in $Y$ for $X$), how to check for independency $\left(f_X(x)f_Y(y) = f_{XY}(x,y)\right)$ and the probability, but I can't seem to find a way to find the joint density. I can't assume they are independent, so what should I do?

Comment: Do you have a lower bound for $x$ and $y$ also? Otherwise you want a uniform distribution on an unbounded set, which dont exist. Maybe $x^2+y^2 \leq 1$?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be one, but I thought about it and it looks like they are both $U[0,1]$, and they would be independent. But something is bugging me about it.

Comment: Obviously, $(X,Y)$ is supposed to be uniform on the triangle $T$ with vertices $(0,0)$, $(1,0)$, $(0,1)$, whose area is $\frac12$, hence the joint PDF of $(X,Y)$ is $f_{X,Y}=2\cdot\mathbf 1_T$.

Comment: @Did, i need to read the comments before posting :(